# Don't see Flows for Domain Project in MMC

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

didn't have any luck on the Mulesoft forums so I'm asking here. I'm new to Mulesoft / Anypoint and this one's been bugging me for a few days. I create a simple Hello World application in Anypoint Studio and try to add it to a new domain project. I add an http:listener-config to the domain, which looks like this:

```
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
```

I then set the domain of the Hello World project to the new domain by selecting it in the mule-project.xml file. I make sure the Hello World Connector Configuration is set to the one coming from Mule Domain. I then right click my domain project and choose publish to MMC, which succeeds. But after deploying it in MMC, I can't see the flows at all. If I remove the domain and publish just Hello World, then I can see the flows. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you deploy the domain manually? Remember, you have to put it in the "domains" folder (Not in "apps" folder).

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work as I can see the flow now, but I don't see anything on the deployments tab in MMC or the applications tab. Is this a common deployment model? Kind of sucks since this is a lot more steps than just deploying from Anypoint Studio.

Comment: Hello! I'm glad my comment was useful for you! You can deploy the applications on the "deployments" tab but not the domains. We use Jenkins CI so we don't need to make the deployments that way. Alike, you can see  the apps clicking a server on "Servers" tabs.